# Most efficient algorithm to know if undirected graph is connected

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, undirected-graph

I´ve been trying to find an algorithm to search if a graph is connected. The graph is undirected and I only want to find **a** solution (there can be multiple) or if there is none. I was looking for a alg. that performs near linear time, maybe O(logN) or O(NlogN).

Can DFS be up to the task or is there another alternative for this specific problem?

Comment: How is the graph represented?

Comment: Is N the number of vertices or of edges?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on how you define `N`, if `N` is number of vertices, the input itself can be of size `O(N^2)`, and you will be needing to read all of it (unless you have some specific ordering of the input, and than that might change).

DFS runs in `O(|V|+|E|)` (number of nodes + number of edges), and can find if the graph is connected by simply counting the number of new vertices you discover, and when done, checking if this number is `|V|`.