Most efficient way of determining if a subgraph of a graph is connected
Suppose I have a graph given by a Laplacian matrix $L$ corresponding to a regular discretization of $[0,1]^2$, meaning nodes $I={(i,j),\quad i,j=1,\dots,n}$ are connected with $(i+1,j),(i,j+1),(i-1,j),(i,j-1)$. If I have a set of indices J ⊆ I what is the most efficient way of checking whether $J$ is a connected graph or not? What if I have a general adjacency matrix / Laplacian and not this regular Laplacian?
Thanks for reading!

Laplacian matrix: A matrix representation of a graph defined as L = D - A, where D is the degree matrix (a diagonal matrix where each entry represents the degree of a node), and A is the adjacency matrix of the graph.

Regular discretization of [0,1]^2: A method of creating a grid or mesh over the unit square [0,1]^2 by dividing it into smaller, evenly spaced intervals.


BONUS QUESTION:
How does the number of connected subgraphs grow when we augment $n$? Exponentially? Polynomially?
I did not try anything, I don't expect myself to come with the most optimal solution, I know that the number of zero eigenvectors of the Laplacian is the number of connected components, I really doubdt this is the way of doing this. I've seen this post Most efficient algorithm to know if undirected graph is connected, but I feel that the square structure of the mesh I'm describing should make it easier?, also, I don't know really how graphs and subgraphs are represented in the puterhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724587/most-efficient-algorithm-to-know-if-undirected-graph-is-connected besides taking the adjacency matrix and fulminating columns that are not in the index set.
PD: where is latex

Your question isn't getting any traction because you're asking multiple questions, and it's phrased in an overly mathematical way. I think your first question is to determine if a set of points on a square grid are connected (via grid lines). You're not going to be able to answer this in time better than O(|J|), and that complexity is for example achieved by DFS (because the degree of any vertex is at most 4).
